# Почему стоит тире? Приложение ли это?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, тире, приложение

> Заболевание сахарным диабетом характеризуется повышением уровня сахара в крови вследствие отсутствия инсулина — **гормона поджелудочной железы**

Почему стоит тире? «гормон поджелудочной железы», а конкретно слово «гормон» — определяемое слово. Получается, здесь нет обособленного приложения. Получается, тире стоит просто перед пояснением?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Игорь, мне нравятся темы вопросов, которые вы задаете. В них чувствуется стремление к системным  знаниям, в то время как многие ограничиваются очень поверхностными суждениями. В то же время при таком подходе нужно четко знать терминологию, которой вы пользуетесь (об этом тоже мало кто задумывается).

Итак, перед нами **три термина**: определение, приложение, пояснение, а также  конкретное существительное ***«инсулин».*** Его  можно определить различным образом: белок, гормон, регулятор уровня глюкозы в крови, лекарственный препарат и т.д.  В предложении все эти существительные  могут считаться **приложениями**.  Здесь у нас четкое грамматическое определение.

А могут они считаться пояснением?  Здесь уже такой четкости нет. Можно обратиться к **словарю**: **ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**,  2. Поясняющее замечание, объяснение.   Дать п. к тексту.
Можно почитать **Розенталя**: Пояснение — это обозначение одного и того же понятия **другими словами**.

В нашем предложении ***другие слова*** – это и есть другие определения, выраженные существительными. Получается, что пояснение и приложение – это в данном случае **одно и то же.** И ставить тире вы можете по правилам, **изложенным в  двух темах:** § 19. Обособленные приложения. § 23. Пояснительные конструкции.

Она зарисовала древние светильники с **гербом** города Ольвии — **орлом**, парящим над дельфинами (Пауст.); Было ещё одно **препятствие** на пути учёных — **суеверие** островитян;

**Вот и Розенталь говорит об этом**

При одинаковой пунктуации в некоторых случаях сближаются различные по типу определения. Например: ***Рядом с этими домами высятся другие здания — жилые, административные, торговые.***  Возможные толкования: а) однородные определения после обобщающего словосочетания другие здания [см. § 15, п. 5]; б) обособленные определения в конце предложения [см. § 18, п. 1]; в) пояснительные определения (…другие, а именно…) [см. § 10, п. 10]; г) присоединительные определения (бессоюзное присоединение) [см. § 24, п. 6]. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

Итак, получается **четыре варианта, четыре темы**.

**Насколько это удобно?** Я бы сказала, что не очень. Увы, такая фрагментарность – это недостаток этого свода правил, пережиток **«описательного периода»** в русской орфографии. А Новое время еще не наступило. ..

Comment: Премного благодарен! Скажите, пожалуйста, предусмотрен ли на этом форуме личный чат, где можно было бы с вами связаться? И можно ли это сделать каким-нибудь иным образом?